# How to strip capital letters and then put them back in again in the same place?

Tags: python

I need to input a sentence with a mixture of capital and lower case letters, and output the positions of each word. However if one word is in capitals and the same word only in lower case is entered it is counted as a separate word. eg. if book and BOOK is entered these will be counted as 2 separate words. I have tried using the .upper/.lower function, but there is no way to put the capital letters back in after doing so? I need the capital letters to be removed and then put back in again after.

```
    def analyse_sentence():
       sentence=input("Please enter your sentence")
       sentence=sentence.split
       compression(sentence)

    def compression(sentence):
        positions=[]
        Unique_words=[]
    for i in sentence:
      if i not in unique:
         unique.append(i)
         positions.append(unique_words.index(i)+1)
```

Comment: Make a copy and remove the cap letters from the copy.

Comment: please provide a sample of your own code and what exactly is causing problems. as @Marichyasana mentioned, the solution could be something as simple as using a separate reference but it is quite unclear whether or not this can be done without seeing your own implementation.

Comment: What is your output supposed to look like?  For example, is it a dictionary with keys for each word and values for the position in the sentence?

Comment: The sentence and positions need to be written to a file and then taken out of the file and printed to the screen with the original capital letters, do I write the copy to the file?

Comment: I have  placed a sample of my code in the description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When posting on stack overflow, you should provide code samples.
What data you have, what your code is, what it does, what you intend to get instead.
It's much easier then to help you.
Anyway, here is my try at helping you :

```
text = 'blabla word1 word2 WORD word book BOOK bLaBlA'
unique_words =  list(set(text.lower().split(' ')))
print('text : %s' % text)
print('unique words : %s' % ','.join(unique_words))
```

**EDIT :**

```
def analyse_sentence():
   sentence = input("Please enter your sentence")
   unique_words =  list(set(sentence.lower().split(' ')))
   print('sentence : %s' % sentence)
   print('unique words : %s' % ','.join(unique_words))
   return unique_words
```

Comment: I have placed the beginning of my code in the description

Comment: This is just returning my sentence in reverse order and with dots in between each word. I inputted the words "hello why not" and it returned the unique words as: not.why.hello. A

Comment: That's normal your sentence is made of unique words. 
try : hello Hello HELLO why Not not Why, and you'll see that it only returns unique words.